# Broken packages for MikTex in 18.04, trouble upgrading them?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 18.04, latex

When installing MikTex (https://miktex.org/download/) I am getting the message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 miktex : Depends: libhunspell-1.3-0 (>= 1.3.3) but it is not installable
          Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not installable
          Depends: libmpfr4 (>= 3.1.3) but it is not installable
          Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried:

```
sudo apt get upgrade && sudo apt get update
```

But still get the same message. Is it that the packages are not compatible with 18.04? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is there any reason why you want MiKTeX instead of TeXLive which is included in Ubuntu's default repositories and doesn't suffer from dependency issues? It also says right there on your linked page "Ubuntu 18.04 – coming soon". TeXLive is generally considered superior to MiKTeX on Linux. See [How to install latex in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](/q/932086/175814)

Comment: Ah, ok I shall try TeXLive.  

I had previously been using MikTeX on Windows 10.  Thanks.